# About Palm distribution

Tags: pr.probability

Can someone explain the Palm distribution? Or provide some information about Palm distribution. The
article called 《A tutorial on Palm distributions for spatial point processes》 is hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C. Palm's theory of spatial point processes relies heavily on measure theory in an abstract setting. A more gentle introduction is given in the lecture notes [Conditioning in spatial point processes](https://data.math.au.dk/publications/csgb/2015/math-csgb-2015-14.pdf). Section 3, in particular, defines the Palm distribution on a finite set of points. This definition involves only elementary concepts.

---

I now notice that these lecture notes are the same source as mentioned in the OP (without a link, so I did not notice earlier). I do think this is the most accessible exposition of the Palm distribution, by considering the finite case first.